# Stuck with java algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, modulo, factorial

I need to write an algorithm that receive 2 numbers (`n` and `k`) and print the result of (`n!%k`).

The problem is that I need to use only int type to solve this, so for `n=18` and `k=71` it prints `-898433024`.
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Try{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);            
        int n = myScanner.nextInt();
        int k = myScanner.nextInt();
        int azeret = 1;
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i=i+1)
        { 
            if (i%k!=0)
                azeret = azeret * (i%k);
        }
        System.out.println(azeret);           
    }            
}
```

Please help me, I'm really lost...

Comment: Factorials are getting large very fast, so its kind of undoable with int per se.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compute-n-under-modulo-p/

Comment: `(a*b) % p = ((a%p) * (b%p)) %p`

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title, so that users with a similar problem can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Almost right!

```
          azeret = (azeret * i) % k;
```

That way, `azeret` stays between `1` and `k`, both of which can be represented in an `int`.